# Как положить в JSON <текущую дату - 23 года> в SOAPUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

Для своих автотестов в SOAPUI мне необходимо подкладывать в JSON <текущую дату - 23 года> или <текущую дату - 23 года + 1 день>.
Пытался это сделать через groovy, но в итоге не получилось.
Так же непонятно как выставить формат даты. Поскольку мне приходиться работать с форматами UNIX (как пример: 1644596770000) и форматом 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Спасибо, Дмитрий! Это действительно помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал использовать библиотеку **java.time** для работы с датой/временем.
То что требуется Вам, можно написать так:

```java
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().minusYears(23).plusDays(1) //1999-06-08
```

Если нужен другой формат даты, то пример такой:

```java
def formattedDate = localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")) //08.06.1999
```

Для работы с UNIX используется класс **Instant**:

```java
def unixTime = 1644596770000
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(unixTime)
def unixDate = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow")).toLocalDate()
```

После чего можно подложить даты в json. Например с помощью **groovy.json.JsonBuilder**:

```java
def json = new JsonBuilder([
        "dateTime": "$formattedDate",
        "unixTime": "$unixDate"
])
println(json.toString())
//Вывод: {"dateTime":"08.06.1999","unixTime":"2022-02-11"}
```

Ссылка на документацию: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html